# How to develop Angular/React in IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition

Tags: angular, reactjs, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, intellij-14

I am new to IntelliJ IDEA, I am using VS Code for Angular and reactJS development. I can see there are several useful features in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition. In VS Code we can install the plugins and add features. Like that can we add a specific set of plugins and make the IntelliJ IDEA Community edition like Ultimate edition for the web development. If YES, what are the plugins I need to install? If NO, what are the alternatives?

Comment: The docs might help: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/javascript-specific-guidelines.html

Comment: @Steve Thank you, I think someone have a prior knowledge can help us easily

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't install JavaScript support in *IDEA Community Edition*, the required plugins are only available in *Ultimate*.
If you can't afford *IDEA Ultimate*, try [WebStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/features/) - it provides advanced coding assistance for Angular and React out of the box and is [less expensive](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/buy/#personal?billing=yearly)

Comment: I am looking for a free option. Can I use eclipse? are there any plugins suitable for the eclipse?

Answer (score 2):

While Community Edition is not support JS, you can use Ultimate Edition EAP, EAP allow you use it 30 days for free, then you have to update it to latest EAP again and you have 30 days more

Comment: thank you for the tip about EAP. thats perfect idea!

Answer (score 1):

TLDR; Use Netbeans for your Node/React work.

One option you may want to consider: Netbeans has an excellent environment for creating and editing Node/React apps.

It's definitely a little sub-optimal/clumsy to run NetBeans alongside IntelliJ simply to get the Node/React ability. But while IntelliJ is a fantastic IDE (JEE, Payara Micro, for me) the IJ Community Edition still does not allow an ability to create/edit/debug Node based applications.  Something Netbeans does a very good job at.

One vote for IntelliJ to enable this ability in their CE

Answer (score 0):

Other alternatives is to use the eclipse ide(It is free)  and download the free version angular plugin.
To download angular plugin in eclipse:
Go to Help->Marketplace->Search Angular Development Tool .
Click on Download .